# Proving Proposition $\forall x\exists y(xy>0\implies y>0)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to show wether or not this holds or not.
 $$\forall x\exists y(xy> 0\implies y>0)$$
For this one I noticed that then $y=0$ it doesn’t hold. But I’m confused wether or not I am done proving or not.

Comment: **Hint:** An implication is considered true when *either* the consequent is true *or* the antecedent is false.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I don't follow. How would I show it in this case?

Comment: @GrahamKemp I don't get it. How have I showed it?

Comment: Because $x0>0\to 0>0$ is vacuously true, then for any $x$ there is an example of $y$ which makes the implication hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simply choose $y=1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We'll split this up into two cases: $x \leq 0$ or $x > 0$.

Let's say $x \leq 0$. Then, since $xy=x$ and $x > 0$ is false, $xy > 0$ must be false. Thus, $xy > 0 \implies y > 0$ is true since the hypothesis is true.

Now let's say $x > 0$. Then, since $xy=x$ and $x > 0$ is true, $xy > 0$ must be true. Also, $y > 0$ is true since $y=1$. Thus, $xy > 0 \implies y > 0$ is true since the conclusion is true.

From the above, we have proven that $(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})(\exists y \in \mathbb{R})(xy > 0 \implies y > 0)$, which is what we wanted.

Comment: So its is true?

Comment: Yes, the proposition you stated in your question is true, as I have just proven.

Answer (score 0):

Take any arbitrary value, $x$.   Is it possible to find an example $y$, for this $x$, such that $xy>0\to y>0$? ( This is not *required* to be the same example for all $x$; we just need to show that there is one example for every one. )

Well, an implication is true if *either* its consequent is true *or* its antecedent is false. ( It is only *falsified* when the consequent is false and the antecedent *true*. )

S0, if we always use $y=0$, then because $0x>0\to 0>0$ is vacuously true for any $x$, then you *have* found what you needed.

> For any $x$ there exists a $y$ such that: $xy>0$ implies $y>0$.

Answer (score 0):

As the earlier answers show, you can choose $\;0\;$ or $\;1\;$ as a value for $\;y\;$, and prove that $\;x y > 0 \implies y > 0\;$ holds for that $\;y\;$, regardless of the choice of $\;x\;$, and that proves your theorem.

But why $\;0\;$ or $\;1\;$?  How did we pull that rabbit out of our hat?  And are those the only numbers that would work?

Let's try a different style of proof here.$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\implies}
\newcommand{\when}{\Longleftarrow}
\newcommand{\equiv}{\Longleftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$  Let's first see if we can simplify $\;x y > 0 \implies y > 0\;$:
$$\calc
    x y > 0 \;\then\; y > 0
\op\equiv\hint{arithmetic: basic property of multiplication}
    (x > 0 \land y > 0) \lor (x < 0 \land y < 0) \;\then\; y > 0
\op\equiv\hints{logic: assume $\;y>0 \;\equiv\; \false\;$ in}\hint{antecedent of $\;\then\;$; simplify antecedent}
    x < 0 \land y < 0 \;\then\; y > 0
\op\equiv\hints{logic: write $\;P \then Q\;$ as $\;\lnot P \lor Q\;$;}
         \hint{simplify using DeMorgan}
    x \ge 0 \;\lor\; y \ge 0 \;\lor\; y > 0
\op\equiv\hint{arithmetic: simplify}
    x \ge 0 \;\lor\; y \ge 0
\endcalc$$

This gives us
$$\calc
    \forall x \exists y (x y > 0 \;\then\; y > 0)
\op\equiv\hint{by the above calculation}
    \forall x \exists y (x \ge 0 \lor y \ge 0)
\op\equiv\hint{logic: extract part without $\;y\;$ out of $\;\exists y\;$}
    \forall x (x \ge 0 \lor \exists y (y \ge 0))
\op\equiv\hint{logic: extract part without $\;x\;$ out of $\;\forall x\;$}
    \forall x (x \ge 0) \;\lor\; \exists y (y \ge 0)
\op\equiv\hints{arithmetic: LHS is false, witness $\;x = -1\;$;}\hint{logic: simplify}
    \exists y (y \ge 0)
\op{\tag{*}\equiv}\hint{witness $\;y = 0\;$, using $\;0 \ge 0\;$}
    \true
\endcalc$$

Looking at the last step $\Ref{*}$, we see that instead of $\;0\;$, which is the simplest choice, also $\;1\;$, and indeed any non-negative $\;y\;$ can be used as witness.